# jQuery social buttons plugin 'not working'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/socialbutton

Implementation: http://alblaw.icvmgroup.net/index.cfm?pageid=12&itemid=835

I'm not new to JavaScript or jQuery by any means, but I'm at a loss with this implementation. I have the following, yet the plugin does not function and I get no errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/socialbutton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.google_plusone').socialbutton('google_plusone');

    // Facebook / Like button
    $('.facebook_like').socialbutton('facebook_like');

    // Facebook / Share button
    $('.facebook_share').socialbutton('facebook_share');

    // Twitter / Tweet Button
    $('.twitter').socialbutton('twitter');

</script>
<div id="social-share">
    <div class="google_plusone"></div>
    <div class="facebook_like"></div>
    <div class="facebook_share"></div>
    <div class="twitter"></div>
</div>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: try putting your html code before your javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your jQuery inside a `$(document).ready();` function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.google_plusone').socialbutton('google_plusone');

  // Facebook / Like button
  $('.facebook_like').socialbutton('facebook_like');

  // Facebook / Share button
  $('.facebook_share').socialbutton('facebook_share');

  // Twitter / Tweet Button
  $('.twitter').socialbutton('twitter');
});
```

Comment: Every part of my being wants to delete this question for missing something so glaringly obvious...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your calls in a `$(function(){ });` ??